# Lombok @SuperBuilder doesn't take parameters

Tags: java, lombok

Assuming two simple classes:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Party {

    protected Long id;
    protected String status;
}
```

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Person extends Party {

    private String name;
    private Long sex;
}
```

The compilation fails on the following error. Upon reading [Lombok | @SuperBuilder](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder) I have no idea what I could miss.

> ```
> C:\Dev\companyproject\src\main\java\com\companyproject\entity\Person.java:12
> java: type com.companyproject.entity.Party.PartyBuilder does not take parameters
> ```

Comment: Let me quote the inline JavaDoc of SuperBuilder: *"All classes in the hierarchy must be annotated with @SuperBuilder."* ... you're using the normal `@Builder` in your parent class, instead of the correct `@SuperBuilder`.

Comment: @Tom: I understood the hierarchy as *everything below and excluding the root*. You might want to compose an answer as `@SuperBuilder` on the `Party` works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue here is the incorrect `@Builder` annotation on the parent class. The [documentation for `@SuperBuilder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder) mentions:

> Most importantly, it requires that *all superclasses* also have the `@SuperBuilder` annotation.

So the correct parent class would be:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder     // <- annotation replaced here
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Party {

    protected Long id;
    protected String status;
}
```

---

**Addendum:**

A key difference between both annotations is that `@SuperBuilder` also creates a constructor of the class expecting a corresponding builder argument.

For `Party` it would look like:

```
protected Party(PartyBuilder<?, ?> b) {
    this.id = b.id;
    this.status = b.status;
}
```

and for `Person`:

```
protected Person(PersonBuilder<?, ?> b) {
    super(b);
    this.name = b.name;
    this.sex = b.sex;
}
```

As you can see, the child class constructor wants to pass its own builder to the parent class constructor and this will only be possible if there is a matching constructor there, and `@Builder` wouldn't generate it.

Also `PersonBuilder<>` extends `PartyBuilder<>`, that is why calling `super` with the child type builder works fine here.